# Pros and cons IPV6 vs stretched vlans

Tags: networking, ipv6, vlan, ipv4

I'm having a hard time finding information about whether implementing ipv6 or using a stretched vlan is a better option for geographically dispersed sites is better.  Does anyone know:

1. Problems with stretched vlans (mac address broadcasting etc)
2. costs for devices to solve those problems
3. pros for using IPv6 instead

EDIT. What I am looking for is pros and cons against implementing the equipment required to implement stretched IPv4 vlans vs simply using IPv6 to solve the same problems. Eg admins stretch vlans instead of route because protocol X can't be routed, but IPv6 can encapsulate protocol X so there is no need to worry about that problem.

Edit 2:  Lets say that one of the problems to be solved is migrating VMs across physical datacenters,  Will IPv6 solve the problem of needing to stretch the vlan?

I am looking for a detailed explanation of which project will provide the most bang for the buck as well as reduce network complexity.  So far the answers have centered around them as if they are not related (which I see as them being related as IPv6 removes vlan requirements entirely- making it extremely difficult to implement any vlan stretching infrastructure) - but have the same requirements of supporting multiple datacenters in a dispersed environment.  All of my providers support IPv6 and we'll probably get a provider independent /48 (if we go that route)

Comment: Stretched VLANs is layer-2 and IPv6 is layer-3. This question is asking to compare apples to oranges...

Comment: I think he knows that, that's why he's asking what he's asking. It would probably be a lot more answerable if he explained the problem he's trying to solve more fully. "geographically-dispersed sites" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: @SanderSteffan yes the layers are different but what are the pros and cons of each one?  If you had to replicate data (as a task) which one would you choose?

Comment: What protocol X can be encapsulated in ipv6, that can not be encapsulated in ipv4 and thus be routed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the problems related to migrating VMs between physical data centres IPv6 will not make a difference. IPv6 is routed in the same way as IPv4, so you would need stretched VLANs in both cases.

As mentioned previously stretched VLANs are not such a great idea. You might want to consider [LISP](http://tools.ietf.org/wg/lisp/charters) for this. Cisco has some very good support for that these days, and VM mobility is something they specifically target on the Nexus 7000 (see [Nexus 7000 NX-OS Innovations](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/switches/ps9441/ps9402/nexus_7000.html)) in their LISP implementation (see [Cisco Locator/ID Separation Protocol for Virtual Machine Mobility](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6554/ps6599/ps10800/at_a_glance_c45-646350.pdf)). And best of all: it supports both IPv4 and IPv6 :-)

Comment: The problem I see with all of the stretched clan proposals is they all want some proprietary magic, with ipv6 all I seem to need is a vpn tunnel (or so it seems)

Comment: An IPv6 VPN tunnel is just the same as an IPv4 VPN tunnel. Both are just two different layer-3 protocols. It doesn't change anything with regard to having to stretch a clan or not.

Comment: can you go in to further details about how ipv6 tunnels are the same as IPv4.  When I suggest that its the same to some of the networking contacting companies they look at me like I have 3 heads.  basically ipv4 tunnels require equipment and ipv6 doesn't (so I'm told)

Answer (score 4):

You are asking about things that are orthogonal to each other (independent of each other) as if you need to make a choice to implement one or the other. Why?

If you have an IPv4 network between two locations then for simple tasks like copying data between the two locations, there's nothing that IPv6 will do for you that IPv4 can't already do.

As a separate question, you might want to extend vlans to the other location, perhaps because you want to avoid the overhead of a router. This motivation for using stretched vlans would be equally valid for IPv4 or IPv6.

One thing has nothing to do with the other.

You mentioned protocols that can't be routed. Non-IP protocols? In that case you should use stretched vlans. Switching to IPv4 to IPv6 won't suddenly make these protocols routable. You also mentioned tunelling these unroutable protocols in IP (and this tunnel carrier could be either v4 or v6, either one is good). I would not recommend tunelling unless necessary because it will add much more overhead than stretched vlans and complicate the network topology a lot. You should resort to this kind of tunelling if the stretched vlans solution is unscalable or unavailable. Reasons why stretched vlans might be unscalable could porentially include limits of spanning tree protocol capabilities, or MAC address leaning difficulties due to unidirectional layer 2 network flows or too many hosts on a single vlan. Reasons why stretched vlans might be unavailable could include a third party router in the link which is outside of your control and cannot be replaced with a bridge.

Comment: so if you had a preference why stay with IPv4 and encapsulate instead of v6 and potentially flatten the address space and reduce the number of routers

Comment: Reread my answer as well as almost everybody else's comments. IT'S NOT A CHOICE BETWEEN STAYING WITH IPv4 **OR** FLATTENING THE ADDRESS SPACE. Please (1) state which protocol X you're talking about that needs encapsulation because it supposedly can't be routed, and (2) why you think that using IPv6 somehow "flattens" the address space.

Comment: it IS a choice between ipv6 or stretched vlans because I only have budget for 1 of those projects.  I think that Ipv6 allows me to eliminate vlans altogether, and eliminate any stretched vlan voodoo and just create a vpn tunnel

Comment: IPv6 enables you to do no such thing. Nothing you can't already do in IPv4, anyway.

Comment: can you explain why you can't eliminate vlans?  IPv6 doesn't do broadcast so I don;t need to create seperate broadcast domains and can keep a flat address space.

Comment: If you don't use separate broadcast domains between your 2 sites then by definition you are stretching the vlan(s) across both sites. This has all of the pitfills and dangers of large broadcast domains that myself and others have pointed out, like spanning tree problems. To quote,"Layer 2 data center interconnects are basically a horrible idea.". If you keep your broadcast domains small and *don't* stretch them across your 2 sites, then you will need to tunnel protocol X (btw, you've still not said what protocol X is) because it can't be routed. All of this is equally true for IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: doesn't IPv6 resolve the STP problem by not having broadcasts?  DLC is an example of a nonroutable protocol for AS/400

Comment: That is a non sequitur. The fact that IPv6 doesn't have have broadcast addresses at layer 3 and doesn't originate any packets with layer 2 broadcast destination address implies nothing about the broadcast or nonbroadcast nature of the layer 2 network or the requirement for STP or anything else at layer 2. Besides, IPv6 still originates multicast packets, which isn't much different from broadcast!

Comment: As for DLC, OK, good example of nonroutable protocol. My original answer stands: if your network is simple enough that you can stretch vlans across sites without creating headaches, then do that. Otherwise tunnel it in IP (either v4 or v6, it makes no difference). If you stretch vlans, consider stretching only the AS/400 vlans across sites and leave the IP vlans routed. This will limit your exposure to the nastiness of large layer 2 networks.

Answer (score 0):

Layer 2 data center interconnects are basically a horrible idea. See http://blog.ioshints.info/2011/11/busting-layer-2-data-center.html for a great explanation.

You want to route between your sites, which means different subnets and an L3 switch or router (even if that router is just a server configured with static routing).

Comment: Even MPLS as a layer2 interconect?

Comment: @Tom O'Connor: Yes, even MPLS is bad in this scenario. Putting dispersed sites into the same L2 broadcast domain for whatever reason is a bad idea unless they are really close (like under 1 km) and the links are totally private. Ultimately, there will be IP with ARP and other Ethernet broadcasts running on top of your MPLS pseudo-wire. I know Metro Ethernet providers love to sell "a big layer 2 domain", but that is not a good idea for all the reasons mentioned in the link. MPLS is good for a lot of use cases, but stretching an Ethernet broadcast domain isn't one.

Comment: but since IPV6 doesn't do broadcast like that wouldn't that solve the broadcast problem?

Comment: IPv6 does lots of layer 2 multicast on the local link, some of which are basically broadcasts (such as neighbor discovery, which replaces ARP). The end result is the same. Most ipv6 host do things like multicast name resolution as well, which is basically broadcast to all ipv6 hosts.

Comment: Multicast is not broadcast as multicast only goes to some devices.  Neighbor discovery in at the application layer unlike arp with is at the network layer and uses the link local address.

Comment: I think his point is that the packets are still sent out to everyone, which makes it a broadcast (because everyone is in the multicast group). Feel free to call it multicast that goes to every single device instead though...

Comment: Exactly. Run wireshark on an IPv6 LAN with 100 machines. There are even more packets sent to all ports than IPv4 broadcasts. They're called technically multicast, but when all hosts are in the multicast group, you might as well call them broadcasts.

Comment: So I did run wireshark and founf that there were only multicasts meaning packets were sent on the wire addressed to multicast and didn't cause any broadcast storms.

Comment: @Jim B: Most IPv6 multicast "control" packets are sent to the "all hosts" groups and ARE EFFECTIVELY BROADCASTS. They will all cross your long-distance L2 link, and be echoed on most switch ports on both sides. So what is the traffic level per host you observe with Wireshark? That's what will be crossing your inter-DC link in both directions. And when some of those packets are lost, hosts will be re-broadcast them.
The link failure modes for long-distance L2 are also ugly (especially with spanning tree). Can it be made to work? Maybe. But it is not the simplest or most reliable solution.

Comment: I saw no packets addressed to any global scopes (or even org scopes), and this is consistent with what I can find that no control traffic is scoped to all hosts.  Where did you get this information?